# How to "safely" use polymorphism with generic template?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I have an interface that a few of classes implements it:

```
interface Vehicle {}

class Car implements Vehicle {}

class Bicycle implements Vehicle {}
```

And I have another interface that has getter and setter of this:

```
interface Person {
    public ArrayList<Vehicle> getVehicles();
    public void setVehicles (ArrayList<Vehicle> vs);
}
```

And a few of classes implement it:

```
class CarOwner implements Person {
    public ArrayList<Car> cars;
    public ArrayList<Car> getVehicles() {
        return cars;
    }
    public void setVehicles(ArrayList<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }
}

class BicycleOwner implements Person {
//...
}
```

However it complains the setter has the same erasure as the interface but does not override it. I had to change the `ArrayList<Vehicle>` to `ArrayList`, and cast it in the function, but it is not "safe" (I know it should work but others may not). How to deal with this situation?

---

**Edit:**

As I changed my code to the answers, it stopped complaining. But when I use it, e.g.

```
//I have an arraylist of Person
ArrayList<Person> persons;
//...
Vehicle first = persons.get(0).getVehicles().get(0);
```

The first line it complains the type requires a parameter... But it could be any type of person because the `Arraylist persons` can contain all types of Person.. How can do this? Or it has to leave it without template parameter?

---

**Edit2:**

I updated the answer down there and found when I call the setter it raises error again...

```
Person<?> personA = persons.get(0);
ArrayList<Vehicle> vs = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
//vs.add(carA);    
personA.setVehicles(vs);
```

The last line gives error: `This gives error saying The method setVehicles(ArrayList<capture#6-of ?>) in the type Post<capture#6-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Vehicle>)`. I tried to change to `ArrayList<?>` but it does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your interface is declared to accept an `ArrayList<Vehicle>`, but you are trying to implement it with a method which takes an `ArrayList<Car>`.  Someone could call your interface and legally hand it a list of some other type extending vehicle, so your code won't compile.

What you want to do is make your `Person` interface generic, so that it can take any type which extends `Vehicle`, then make `CarOwner` be a class implementing `Person<Car>`:

```
interface Person<T extends Vehicle> {
    public ArrayList<T> getVehicles();
    public void setVehicles (ArrayList<T> vs);
}

class CarOwner implements Person<Car> {
    public ArrayList<Car> cars;
    public ArrayList<Car> getVehicles() {
        return cars;
    }
    public void setVehicles(ArrayList<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }
}
```

### Edit to respond to the question's edit

Well, if you're going to have a raw `ArrayList<Person>`, you are really just moving your type error from the class definition to the use of it.  Once you parameterize `Person`, you need to also use it that way:

```
    ArrayList<Person<?>> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...
    Vehicle first = persons.get(0).getVehicles().get(0);
```

You can learn more about wildcards in Java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

### Edit2

Yes, the drawback of wildcards is the compiler doesn't know the type. In this case you can just use the  `Vehicle` interface, since you do know the type everything is extending:

```
    ArrayList<Person<Vehicle>> persons = new ArrayList<Person<Vehicle>>();
    // ...
    Person<Vehicle> personA = persons.get(0);
    ArrayList<Vehicle> vs = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    //vs.add(carA);    
    personA.setVehicles(vs);
```

Comment: @texasbruce  I've updated my answer to reflect the changes in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Make your interface generic.

```
interface Person<T extends Vehicle> {
   public ArrayList<T> getVehicles();
   public void setVehicles (ArrayList<T> vs);
}

class CarOwner implements Person<Car> {...}
```

In response to edit, use generic wildcard

```
//I have an arraylist of Person
ArrayList<Person<?>> persons;
//...
Vehicle first = persons.get(0).getVehicles().get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Person instances are intended to own vehicles of a particular type, why not introduce a type parameter for that type?

```
interface Person<V extends Vehicle> {
    ArrayList<V> getVehicles();
    void setVehicles (ArrayList<V> vs);
}

class CarOwner implements Person<Car> {
    public ArrayList<Car> cars;
    public ArrayList<Car> getVehicles() {
        return cars;
    }
    public void setVehicles(ArrayList<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the generic type to be able to vary by implementing class, you'll need to make `Person` generic. Something like:

```
interface Person<V extends Vehicle> {
    ArrayList<V> getVehicles();
}

class CarOwner implements Person<Car>
    @Override
    public ArrayList<Car> getVehicles() {
        return cars;
    }
}
```

Note also that defining such a specific type as `ArrayList` in an interface is poor design; there's almost never any reason to restrict return types that narrowly. In this case, if you really needed to have random-access characteristics, you could return `RandomAccessList`, but `List` or even `Collection` is generally a better option.